# Specifying multiple converter dictionaries when reading multiple sheets with pandas.read_excel()

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have an xlsx file with multiple sheets. Each sheet has a separate table with different columns. I am using

```
    pandas.read_excel(sheet_name=None)
```

to read in all sheets at once. I want to specify the datatype for each column in each sheet separately.

The "converters" argument in read_excel() takes a dictionary of {column_name:column_type} pairs, but this would only help me if all the sheets had the same columns. How do I set a different "converters" argument for each sheet I read in?

Comment: Can't you provide a dictionary with the names of all the columns across all sheets? or do you have a case where the same column exists on more than one sheet and needs to use a different converter on every sheet?

Comment: If every sheet has a different table with different columns, then you will most likely need a different dataframe for each sheet. Rethink about the problem...
If you need you can concatenate all dataframes in a second step, neverthless I'd consider loading each sheet in a different df.

Comment: @FabricioFonseca `read_excel` already returns a dict `{sheet_name: df}` if `sheet_name` is `None`

Comment: @DeepSpace, yes it's possible that (for example) sheet '1' column 'a', could have a different dtype to sheet '3' column 'a'. I have 13 dataframes, anywhere between 6 and 34 columns in each dataframe. Some column titles are unique, others are not. Sometimes data types are consistent across columns with the same name, sometimes they are not. At the moment I'm resorting to reading in all dataframes and then converting dtypes individually.

Comment: @FabricioFonseca, I do have a different dataframe for each sheet. I'm trying to convert dtypes for all of them as I read them in instead of going through each one afterwards.